# regenerating Android & IOS folders inside react native project

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I removed Android & IOS folder , to recreate them again

however I can't find a way in RN version 0.61.5 to return these folders again

`react-native eject` > is not working
`react-native upgrade --legacy true` > error: unknown option `--legacy'
react-native upgrade > Specified version "0.61.5" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.61.5" semver range. No need to upgrade

any modern solution ?

Comment: You can start a new project, and copy your js code.

Comment: Abraham , yes I had to did this , do you know how to change the title in the launch screen ?

Comment: @AbrahamHernandez It's not a good way to do it in this way if I have a big project and do a lot of stuff why I should do it from began?

Comment: @DevAS, It appears React Native got rid of that command as stated https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/808#issuecomment-554211942. Goodluck

Comment: @DevAS if you have a big project you probably use git, so you can manage to get things back like they use to be, or you don't delete the ios and android folders.